# Access-Control-Allow-Origin with HLS streaming and video JS

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, cors, m3u8, http-live-streaming

I'm using videoJs to play some HLS stream and video.
It's working fine on phones, tablets and Safari but i'm having some troubles with chrome and Firefox

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'xxxxxxx' is therefore not allowed access.

OR

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'xxxxxxx' is therefore not allowed access.

I tried to use Ben Alman PHP proxy (http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/) to get the M3U8 file with no success.

Also, I don't have access to the server hosting the file, so i can't change the Access-Control header.

I'm not a skilled web developer, so if anyone could help, it would be awesome.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try to verify if your server has CORS activated. As long as you know the public ip of the server you can check it.  http://client.cors-api.appspot.com/client

Then , what do you use for publishing your videos/live streams. For example for wowza to work with videojs you have to set cors on wowza and not on the web server.